# Book featuring an airplane sheet-plated with gold and an expedition to Africa to get it?

Tags: identification-request

I didn't read the book itself, but listened to it being read in a series of radio auditions, in the end of 1980s. The book was in Polish translation, or, possibly, it was by Polish author.

More details, as I remember those: The setting is in Africa, vaguely 1970s-ish (or 1980s-ish, even?). Some country has recently driven off their dictator. For some reason there's a small group of special forces going in to get out the dictator's personal plane. They are armed with M16s and with some other kind of a (fictional?) assault rifle having 100 rounds in magazine.

Then the usual slog through the jungle ensues, and in the end they get the plane, but with a heavy plot twist. And the plane as it happens is coated with gold sheets manufactured from the complete gold reserve of the country, and is very heavy and difficult to take off in and fly.

In the group there was a big black fellow nicknamed Dog or Doc and a deceivingly nerd-ish specialist, nicknamed (maybe) Ryder. The main character was maybe nicknamed Scorpion (but I'm really uncertain about *that*).

Comment: This sounds hauntingly familiar. I don't remember the guns aspect, but I do remember the too-heavy plane and their struggle to get it to take off with the runway they had.

Comment: In the group there was a big black fellow nicknamed Dog or Doc and a deceivingly nerd-ish specialist, nicknamed (maybe) Ryder. The main character was nicknamed (maybe) Scorpion.

Comment: Please edit into the question any information you have; comments can be deleted (and not everyone reads them!).

Comment: There's Border Line by Joyce Keener: https://www.paperbackswap.com/BORDER-LINE-JOYCE-KEENER/book/514679/ which might fit some of the details but not quite, it seems.